# Amazon S3 AWS upload image to a folder

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading

A quick help here, i wan to achieve an upload of my images to my amazon S3 bucket, i'm able to achieve that with following code.

```
    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client( new BasicAWSCredentials( getString(R.string.s3_access_key), getString(R.string.s3_secret)));
//params contains file path
                        //PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest( getString(R.string.s3_bucket), params[0].getName(), params[0]);  
                        PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest( getString(R.string.s3_bucket), params[0].getName(), params[0]);
                        s3Client.putObject(por);

                        ResponseHeaderOverrides override = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
                        override.setContentType( "image/jpeg" );
                        urlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest( getString(R.string.s3_bucket), params[0].getName() );
                        urlRequest.setExpiration( new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000 ) );  // Added an hour's worth of milliseconds to the current time.
                        urlRequest.setResponseHeaders( override );
```

There is a folder in my bucket I'm not able to upload images to that folder.

what i tried for uploading images to `folder` into bucket is this

```
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest( getString(R.string.s3_bucket), params[0].getName(), params[0]).withKey("testmorya/");
                    s3Client.putObject(por);
```

**BUCKET NAME : morya
FOLDER NAME : testmorya**

Help appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is all about how you structure your key. To put "filea" into "folderb", just name the key of the object as "folderb/filea".

Comment: not so clear can you please add some more description

Comment: when you form a put request, you give a bucket and a key, right? bucket is obviously morya as you stated. Now as for the key, you said your folder is testmorya, assume your file name is foo, then the key in this case is "testmorya/foo".

Comment: Yeah thanks, it has been uploaded to folder, but i'm not able to get the URL where it has been saved, like it's saved here http://pastebin.com/wQAcHKkE (it contains the link). But what i'm getting back is is this http://pastebin.com/7ZxprPSP (it contains the link).

Comment: can you please help in this.

Comment: do you have access to the AWS console? you can find out the URL from there.

Comment: yes, i'm having access to console, but i need that URL to be saved at my other server. so that i can reuse it.

Comment: I need that URL to be reverted back to me so that I can save that url to my server and use it where ever i want to.

Comment: go to the console, select the file and take a look at its properties. One of the property is link, and that's the url to use. But you also need to make sure that your file has the correct ACL, so that it is available to the right audience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60321/discussion-between-nitin-misra-and-peter-pei-guo).